# Loop Between 2 Dates Adding A Day on Each Time Of The Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if the following is possible. I have 2 dates, lets say they are:

20/11/2015 and 25/11/15

I have a SQL query that I need to run searching between 2 dates for each day from 5 days before the first date up until 5 days after the last date.  My simple statement is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE 
FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN 'DATE1' AND 'DATE2'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
print "<tr><td>" . $row['DATE'] . "<td>" . $row['ROOM'] . "</td><td>" . $row['USER_ID'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Now I want this to loop through the following dates replacing DATE1 AND DATE2 in the statement with the following:

```
15/11/2015 AND 16/11/2015 (5 days before 1st date and the next day)
16/11/2015 AND 17/11/2015
```

And so on up until 5 days after the last date so:

```
29/11/2015 AND 30/11/2015
```

So I assume first of all I need to get the date 5 days before and then add a day on which will get me the first two between days and then keep adding a day on each until 5 days after which will be the last day.  I am not sure how to do this.  Your help would be appreciated.

The end result should look like this:

```
| Date       | Room Type     | User ID
| 15/11/2015 | Double        | 3
| 15/11/2015 | Twin          | 4
| 16/11/2015 | Shared Double | 9
| 24/11/2015 | Single        | 6
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
For @Days = 0 to ?? Step 5
    ...
next
```

to loop the query and

```
WHERE DATE > ('DATE1',INTERVAL @Days DAY) AND DATE < ('DATE2',INTERVAL @Days DAY)
```

(I don't like between)

Or else you can use this trick:

```
for ($date = strtotime("2014-01-01"); $date < strtotime("2014-02-01"); $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) {
echo date("Y-m-d", $date)."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to create the dates is to use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and a [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

First you can create a `$date1` and a `$date2` using the dates from your example: '20/11/2015' and '25/11/15'.

You can use the `modify` function on the DateTime class to add and subtract 5 days.

Then create a `$dateInterval` for 1 day as the interval for the dateperiod.
Then create a `$datePeriod` which you can loop using a `foreach` construct.

For example:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '20/11/2015');
$date1->modify('-5 days');

$date2= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '25/11/15');
$date2->modify('+5 days');

$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod(
    $date1, $dateInterval ,$date2
);

foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",
        $date->format("d/m/Y"),
        $date->modify('+1 days')->format("d/m/Y")
    );
    echo "$sql<br>";
}
```

This will echo the queries with the dates:

```
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '15/11/2015' AND '16/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '16/11/2015' AND '17/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '17/11/2015' AND '18/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '18/11/2015' AND '19/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '19/11/2015' AND '20/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '20/11/2015' AND '21/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '21/11/2015' AND '22/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '22/11/2015' AND '23/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '23/11/2015' AND '24/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '24/11/2015' AND '25/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '25/11/2015' AND '26/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '26/11/2015' AND '27/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '27/11/2015' AND '28/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '28/11/2015' AND '29/11/2015'
SELECT USER_ID, ROOM, DATE FROM booking_table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '29/11/2015' AND '30/11/2015'
```